# How non-local can the interactions be for Density Matrix Renormalization Group (DMRG) to still work?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, renormalization, computational-physics, spin-chains, tensor-network

I know that Density Matrix Renormalization Group (DMRG) / Tensor Networks (TN) work well for local Hamiltonians, where on each site I have a fermion or boson, which only have nearest-neighbor interactions. Now assume a model in which $k$ sites which are at most $d$ steps apart can interact with each other. How should the bond dimension scale with $d$ and $k$ in order for DMRG to still be able to produce reasonable results? Something like $O(\operatorname{e}^k, \operatorname{e}^d)$?

Comment: I think the question should be how the bond dimension has to scale with $d$ and $k$. (Also, the way in which $k$ and $d$ appear in the question is somewhat confusing ... you ask about $d$ and end with a guess not involving $d$.)

Comment: Quite clearly exponential in $d$, as this includes 2D systems, where the area law implies a linear scaling of the entanglement in $d$. The $e^k$-scaling does not seem to make much sense given the $e^d$-scaling, as $d\ge k$.